# jQuery scrollTop Not Working On Same Viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to achive to jump through two anchors on same screen viewport but as long as both are visible, jquery is only focusing on the anchor which is at the top.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="jump" id="1"></a>
<p>Content 1</p>
<a class="jump" id="2"></a>
<p>Content 2</p>
<a class="jump" id="3"></a>
<p>Content 3</p>

<style>
    .jump {
        margin-top: 300px;
        display: block;
    }

    body {
        padding-bottom: 500px;
    }
</style>

<script>
    var currentTarget = 0;
    var timer;
    var targets = new Array();
    $(".jump").each(function () {
        targets.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });

    $(function () {
        $(window).on('wheel', function (e) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            var delta = e.originalEvent.deltaY;
            timer = setTimeout(function () {
                if (delta > 0) {
                    if (currentTarget < targets.length) {
                        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#' + targets[currentTarget]).offset().top }, 1000);
                        console.log(targets[currentTarget]);
                        currentTarget++;

                        if (currentTarget >= targets.length) {
                            currentTarget = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }

                else {
                    console.log("Scroll Went Up");
                }
            }, 250);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Is there any workaround for focusing on both. Any jQuery or JavaScript solutions are accepted.

Comment: Please make a snippet with an example of your code/problem. Otherwise we cannot help you. Replicate your problem first

Comment: Originally, it is way more complicated but i narrowed down the problem to this. Anyways, i will add it in couple of minutes.

Comment: @MihaiT i have updated the question. Any ideas?